# Iterate all controls in BindingNavigator

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, toolstripbutton

I have some windows forms that each has some controls including buttons,ComboBox,... and also in each form i have a Bindingnavigator control that i added some new Toolstrip buttons to it, how can i write a general method that get 3 parameters and iterate all controls on a form(including that toolstrip buttons) and enable/disable Enabled status of an special control?
my method signature is like this:

```
Public SetStatusOf(Form frm,string controlName,bool status)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the question, and from what I understood, you need this:

```
    foreach (Control c in frm.Controls)
    {
        if (c.Name.Equals(controlName))
            c.Enabled = status;
    }
```

but you can also directly use

```
frm.Controls[controlName].Enabled = status;
```

Comment: but 2 things: 1- with this code snippet i couldn't iterate all controls(controls with child controls) 2-ToolStripButton does not inherited from Control class